# Why is my left join not working on two fields where one was parsed?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table and a query that I want to join. The fields that I need to compare are Job/JobParse and Suffix/SuffixParse. The parsed fields came from **dbo_JOB000** using RIGHT and LEFT functions to pull out the string. It may be useful to note that in the Table the Job field is of type `text` and the Suffix field is of type `number`.

**dbo_job**

```
job               suf    job_date        Uf_Production_Line
H000001534        23      6/1/2015        LN4200
```

**dbo_RESSCHD000**

```
RESID         JOBTAG       STARTDATE 
LN4200         147          6/8/2015 6:00:00 AM
LN4200         147          6/8/2015 2:00:00 PM
```

**dbo_JOB000**

```
JOBTAG                  JSID
147        .H000001534          .00023.0000000010
```

**qry_Schedule** - this query is built using **dbo_RESSCHD000** and **dbo_JOB000**

```
SELECT 
    dbo_JOB000.JSID, 
    dbo_RESSCHD000.RESID, 
    dbo_RESSCHD000.GROUPID, 
    dbo_RESSCHD000.STARTDATE, 
    dbo_RESSCHD000.ENDDATE, 
    1 AS NumberofShifts, 
    Right(Left([JSID],11),10) AS JobParse, Left(Right([JSID],13),2) AS SuffixParse, 
    dbo_RESSCHD000.STATUSCD
    FROM dbo_JOB000 INNER JOIN dbo_RESSCHD000 ON dbo_JOB000.JOBTAG = dbo_RESSCHD000.JOBTAG
WHERE 
(((dbo_RESSCHD000.STARTDATE)>=Date()) AND ((dbo_RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)<=Date()+([Forms]![MainForm]![Text43]-1)) AND ((dbo_RESSCHD000.STATUSCD) Not Like "S"))
ORDER BY 
    dbo_JOB000.JSID;
```

**qry_JobCompare** - this query is built using **dbo_job** and **qry_Schedule**

```
SELECT 
    qry_Schedule.JobParse, 
    qry_Schedule.SuffixParse, 
    dbo_job.job_date, 
    dbo_job.Uf_Production_Line
FROM qry_Schedule 
LEFT JOIN dbo_job 
    ON qry_Schedule.JobParse = dbo_job.job;
```

The goal is to return the job and suffix information from **qry_Schedule** and then use those to find other corresponding information from the **dbo_job**. For example, I want to use `H000001534` and `23` to find that job in the **dbo_job** and find its job date, line number, etc... But I need to use the query's list of jobs.

The problem is that I am getting the error message "JOIN expression not supported".

Does anyone know how to fix this? Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting brackets around the compared field like this: `left join dbo_job on (qry_Schedule.JobParse = dbo_job.job)` and make sure that the data type of both JobParse and job is the same.

Comment: @zedfoxus where would I specify in the first Query what the JobParse and SuffixParse data types are?

Comment: Is there a problem with *qry_Schedule* itself?  Does this query work? ... `SELECT * FROM qry_Schedule`

Comment: @HansUp the problem is that _qry_Schedule_ does not have the job field parsed. For example, one of the rows has the unparsed ".H000001534          .00023.0000000010" from where I have to extract "H000001534" and "23". How would I join the Table to this query directly?

Comment: could you please update your question according to your comment @hans? The question is unclear. Please include "real" exampledata

Comment: Then I don't understand how you expect to join `ON qry_Schedule.JobParse` Doesn't `qry_Schedule` return the `JobParse` values you displayed in the sample data?

Comment: @swe updated to include real data

Comment: @HansUp I updated the table/query names for clarity.

Comment: I examined your updated question and still don't understand how join `ON qry_Schedule.JobParse = dbo_job.job` could trigger the error you reported.  Can you share a copy of your database?

Comment: @HansUp I wish I could to get this problem solved quicker but it's my company's data :/ What do you need to know? I can fill you in here

Comment: Discard the confidential data and add in just enough dummy data to illustrate the problem you're trying to solve.  We only need *dbo_job* and *qry_Schedule* plus any table(s) the query pulls from.

Comment: @HansUp how's that? FYI - dbo_job, dbo_RESSCHD000 and dbo_JOB000 have tons more fields but they aren't used so it didn't make sense to include them.

Comment: You said *"the problem is that `qry_Schedule` does not have the job field parsed."*  Yet the query SQL includes `Right(Left([JSID],11),10) AS JobParse`  I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry about that! That's a remnant of my oversimplification from the beginning. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the equals operator to compare text fields.  Try using the 'like' keyword.

SELECT 
    qry_Schedule.JobParse, 
    qry_Schedule.SuffixParse, 
    dbo_job.job_date, 
    dbo_job.Uf_Production_Line
FROM qry_Schedule 
LEFT JOIN dbo_job 
    ON ( qry_Schedule.JobParse like dbo_job.job );

You also can't index a text field so this may be slow for large tables.  Ideally the Job field would be a varchar or nvarchar type so that it can be indexed and the = operator can be used.

Comment: I pasted this directly over my code and it doesn't work. I get the same "JOIN expression not supported" error.

Comment: Does putting brackets around the join condition help?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried right after pasting directly, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can put brackets as

```
SELECT qry_Schedule.JobParse, 
       qry_Schedule.SuffixParse, 
       dbo_job.job_date, 
       dbo_job.Uf_Production_Line
  FROM qry_Schedule INNER JOIN dbo_job ON (qry_Schedule .id_field=dbo_job.id_field);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, the problem seems to be, that you have a value in one of your tables, which you have to parse first and join then.

I would use a subselect.

`select * from (
select substring(bla,23,2) as jobParse, <otherfields> from qry_Schedule) as innertab left join dbo_job on innertab.job=dbo_job.job`

or something like that.